# Packaging with tar

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to package the files:

```
file1
folder2/hello
folder2/world
file3
```

into a tar file so they are encapsulated in a custom defined folder, so the `tar -tvf archive.tar` appears as:

```
mycustomfolder/file1
mycustomfolder/folder2/hello
mycustomfolder/folder2/world
mycustomfolder/file3
```

Currently to come around this I am:

- Creating an archive(x) of `file1`, `folder2` and `file3`.
- Creating a `mycustomfolder` folder.
- Extract the archive(x) into `mycustomfolder`
- Create an archive(y) from `mycustomfolder`

I can't help it think their might be one step of doing this or a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the archive to extract into its own directory -- which is generally better, since ones that don't can make a mess -- just create the directory, then move/copy the content tree into it, so you have, as in your second example:

```
mycustomfolder/file1
mycustomfolder/folder2/hello
mycustomfolder/folder2/world
mycustomfolder/file3
```

Then `tar -cvf myarchive.tar mycustomfolder`.  To extract, `tar -xvf myarchive.tar`.

**If you don't want to create the directory first,** you can transform the files names and append a directory prefix:

```
tar --xform="s%^%mycustomfolder/%" -cvf myarchive.tar file1 folder2 file3
```

The transformation (see `man tar`) uses `sed` syntax; I used `%` instead of `/` for the divider because `s/^/mycustomerfolder\//` creates a folder named `mycustomfolder\` (== odd behavior IMO), but `s/^/mycustomfolder//` is (properly) an "Invalid transform expression".

Comment: That is what I am doing as is, I was wondering if you can tell tar to create a directory to put all of its content in

Comment: There's at least a hack for that...I've added a few paragraphs.

Comment: +1 Neat hack! Seems to be a GNUism though.